# 'Contains' function

Tags: r, string, substring

I need to know if there are any functions available in R that allow me to check if one string contains a substring and return a boolean. I've already tried `str_detect` but that doesn't suit my need.

For example:

```
string = 12345REFUND4567
```

and

```
substring = REFUND
```

`contains(string,substring)` would ideally return `TRUE`
since `12345REFUND4567` contains `REFUND`.

`contains(string,substring)` is just the format I'd imagine the function to take.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably are looking for `grepl`:

```
string <- "12345REFUND4567"
grepl("REFUND", string, fixed=TRUE)

[1] TRUE
```